# XsltListViewWebPart build query using variable

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, caml

is possibility send a variable from ParameterBinding to query in XsltListViewWebPart?

```
<Query>
  <Where>
     <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef"/>
      <Value Type="Lookup">
        <xsl:value-of select ="$MyVariable"/>
      </Value>
    </Eq>
 </Where>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on SPD 2010, you can do this conveniently from the UI.
Under List View Tools > Options > Parameters, create a new parameter, then add a filter which uses the newly created parameter. (In SPD 2013 it's similar, but getting the UI to show the List View Tools can be a bit trickier)

You can do this manually too:
add a ParameterBinding (the example is for a querystring parameter; you didn't specify where your parameter will get its value from):

```
<ParameterBinding Name="someParam" Location="QueryString(paramName)" DefaultValue=""/>
```

Then edit your query to look like this:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="SomeField"/>
            <Value Type="Text">{someParam}</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where>
</Query>
```